# Multi-parameter function - Correct usage of *args / **kwargs

Tags: python, optional-parameters, args

I have a function like this one:

```
def hexify_string(aString):
    #code for string2hexa conversion
```

...and I want to have a function who accepts one or more (quantity undefined) parameters, and to return the hexadecimal representation of the sum of the parameters.

```
def hexify(a,b...n):
    #map hexify_string to all the parameters, and return the sum of them
```

Is there a way of doing this using *args / **kwars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*args` takes all non-keyword parameters and turns them into a list. You can map `hexify_string` to each element of the list, and then return the sum of all the elements in the list.

```
def hexify(*args);
    return sum(map(hexify_string, args)
```

This is assuming your `hexify_string` function returns a hex value, not a string.

Comment: Right, `map()` works here as well.  I used the generator expression form of `map()`, which is a common idiom in Python.  The good thing about `map()` is that it doesn't waste time rebinding the loop variable name; it just maps the values.  In Python 2.x your solution will build a list which is then immediately destroyed but in Python 3.x `map()` is lazy and this solution is optimal.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I tried this way, but using "*args" instead of "args" in the function definition. Now it works!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?  Collect any number of arguments, which should all be strings.  Pass each string to `hexify_string()` which returns an integer.  Sum the integers and return the sum.

```
def hexify(*lst):
    n = sum(hexify_string(s) for s in lst)
    return n
```

When you want to collect the arguments, you want to treat them all the same, and you don't know how many there will be, that is exactly what the `*args` syntax was intended for.  This is a perfect use case for it.

`**kwargs` collects `name=value` arguments, and you don't want any of those here.